# Eclipse opens and then immediately closes after graphic appears

Tags: java, eclipse

When windows installed updates, it closed my eclipse and corrupted the workspace or something.   When I try to start eclipse I get the error:

I have already tried most of the google solutions.  I tried deleting the plugins folder, and it still does the same thing.  I tried adding the --clean option to the eclipse launcher, and it still crashes.  If I delete the org.eclipse.e4.workbench folder, it still does the same behavior.  When I try to start eclipse it shows the launcher logo for about a quarter second, and none of the above solutions fixed my problem.

Any other ideas?

Thanks,

```
 The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core 2 0 2015-08-24 08:54:58.371
!MESSAGE Failed to load tasks.xml.zip, restoring from snapshot
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Failed to load Task List
```

Comment: Try renaming your workspace folder, basically backing it up. When you then start Eclipse, it'll create a new empty workspace. If that works, the Eclipse installation is good, but the workspace is corrupt. Reconfigure new workspace and import your projects.

Comment: Still no change in behavior after renaming the folder

Comment: Looks like your plugin got corrupted.  I would suggest setting Eclipse up again from scratch (i.e. download and unzip a fresh distribution)

Comment: Delete everything from workspace and delete the root folder and then unzip again?  Is there anything else that I have to do in order to make sure that it works?  I have unzipped it already before and it did not fix the issue, so I want to make sure that all pieces of it are fixed

Comment: Nope, reextracting the archive and renaming the workspace folder does not fix the issue\

Comment: Do you mean when you download a fresh eclipse zip, unzip it and run it for the first time with a newly created workspace, it doesn't work?

Comment: I dont get the chance to create any workspaces.  I dont even get to that screen.  I renamed my current workspace, and downloaded a fresh copy of eclipse and tried running it with the same result.

Comment: Well, only thing left is your Java installation. Well, and your OS, but let's not go there.

Comment: Ill try uninstalling and reinstalling java then.

Comment: Is the error from the fresh eclipse still about the workspace or is it some other error? Eclipse stores workspace paths in `<eclipse_dir>\configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` so a fresh install shouldn't know anything about workspaces on your system.

Comment: I fixed it.  It was an issue with my java installation.  Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: Open Command Prompt as Administrator

Step 2: Change Your Directory to eclipse folder

Run

Step 3: eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState

Done!

Comment: This worked for me, but I had a different problem! My package explorer was showing as empty! This did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just Uninstall the latest Java updates from ControlPanel->Programs and Features
and Re-Open Eclipse .

Comment: Does that mean the the latest version of Eclipse doesn't work with the latest version of Java SDK?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION IS SIMPLE

Firstly you wil come across this issue if you have uninstalled Java versions from system uninstall window. eg., I uninstalled Java 8 u151 from my machine and downloaded and installed Java 8 u152. Then it was opening with splash screens for few seconds.
Quick Fix is:

```
Undo all your java version changes.
Uninstall 152 for exammple and install the original 151 version. This fixed my issue.
```

> DONT FOGET TO COPY ECLIPSE folder TO c:\program files folder.